# .NET Object to String

Tags: asp.net

I have code like these:

```
<div class="alert alert-custom alert-notice alert-light-primary fade show" role="alert">
    <div class="alert-text">
        <a>Dear, </a>
        @foreach (var item in User.Claims.Take(2))
            {<a>@item.Value</a>}
        <a>. Welcome. </a>
    </div>
```

and it's output like:

> Dear, < MRTGD > < name.surname@test.com >. Welcome.

I get the username and e-mail address from the active directory. Unfortunately, i cant get display name from active directory so i want to get display name from e-mail adress. But i cant use substring function on object.

I need a sample result like these:

> Dear, NAME SURNAME. Welcome.

Do you have any suggestions?

Comment: Even an organisation with a such a standard for emails will have exceptions. Eg. guests from other AADs and name collisions. You would be better getting app access to AD configured to allow access to full names. Also [assuming forename-surname is a mistake.](https://www.kalzumeus.com/2010/06/17/falsehoods-programmers-believe-about-names/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well if the email is always in the expected format you could use:

```
string[] tokens = item.Value.Split('@').First().Split('.');
string name = tokens.First();
string surName = tokens.Last();
```

Comment: with a little arrangement these code is solved my problem.